# How can I color text red without changing its position at all inside a parbox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex, color, overpic, parbox

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheart}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{86}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardiamond}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{87}
\renewcommand{\heartsuit}{\color{red} \varheart}
\renewcommand{\diamondsuit}{\color{red} \vardiamond}

\begin{document}
    \begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/Strike.jpg}
        \put (5,93) {\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering \LARGE \textbf{\textit{
            \color{red}3}} \\
            $\heartsuit$
        }}
    \end{overpic}
    \begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/Strike.jpg}
        \put (5,93) {\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering \LARGE \textbf{\textit{
            3}} \\
            $\heartsuit$
        }}
    \end{overpic}
\end{document}
```

In the first `overpic`, the `3` is red, and in the second `overpic` the `3` is black. Unfortunately, by making the `3` red, it appears that the `\color{red}` command has changed the spacing around the `3` so that it is both higher on the image and also more offset to the right.

**How can I make the `3` colored red without impacting its position?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have line breaks in the code immediately after each `\textbf{\textit{` directive, LaTeX inserts a space. This is evidently not what you want.

You should either terminate the lines with a `%` (comment) character or omit the line breaks in the first place. Furthermore, as David Carlisle has pointed out in a comment, for the sake of robustness you should also use `\textcolor{...}{...}` instead of `\color{...}...`. This is because `\color` moves the first baseline, whereas `\textcolor` does not.

The relevant code snippet should therefore either be

```
\begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/Strike.jpg}
    \put (5,93) {\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering \LARGE \textbf{\textit{%
        \textcolor{red}{3}}} \\
        $\heartsuit$
    }}
\end{overpic}
\begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/Strike.jpg}
    \put (5,93) {\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering \LARGE \textbf{\textit{%
        3}} \\
        $\heartsuit$
    }}
\end{overpic}
```

or

```
\begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/Strike.jpg}
    \put (5,93) {\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering\LARGE\textbf{\textit{\textcolor{red}{3}}} \\
                 $\heartsuit$
    }}
\end{overpic}
\begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/Strike.jpg}
    \put (5,93) {\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering\LARGE\textbf{\textit{3}} \\
                 $\heartsuit$
    }}
\end{overpic}
```

Comment: I switched to `\textcolor` because `\color` at start of a box moves the first baseline (less important in the default vertical centering, but still...)